# Proving two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

$A=\{ e^{\frac{1}{z}}  : 0<|z|<r \}$ where $r \in (0,\infty)$.

$B=\mathbb C /\{0\}$

How can I prove this ?

Comment: First, do you mean $B=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ (set difference)? Second, why is $r$ mentioned? If $0<\lvert z\rvert$ there is always some $r$ in $(0,\infty)$ such that $0<\lvert z\rvert<r$; for example, let $r=\lvert z\rvert+1$. That is, if you can choose different values of $r$ for different elements of $A$ then $r$ is redundant and need not be mentioned. But if $r$ is supposed to be some fixed value then $A$ is not equal to $B$. For example, $\{e^{1/z}:0<\lvert z\rvert<1\}\neq\{e^{1/z}:0<\lvert z\rvert<3\}$ (only one of those sets contains $e^{1/2}$), so they can't both be equal to $B$.

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough points to comment)

I think what you are looking for is [Casorati–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)